# How do I add an editable combobox to a System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, propertygrid, typeconverter

I have a `System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid` with different types of values. For a specific item, I want to show a list of *useful* values to choose from. The user may also type a new value. Something similar to a traditional dropdown combobox:

[image]

So far, I have my own `System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter`, but I can't figure out how to get both the dropdown with suggested values *and* the possibility to edit the value directly. Please help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can accomplish this by implementing your own [UITypeEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor.aspx).

I recommend reading [Getting the Most Out of the .NET Framework PropertyGrid Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx).  In particular, the section titled [Providing a Custom UI for Your Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx#usingpropgrid_topic7) walks through how to make a custom control for a specific property.

Comment: Inheriting `System.ComponentModel.StringConverter` solved the problem. Obviously, text editing cannot be done with other types than strings. Thanks for the links though!

Answer (score 8):

It is easy. In your own `StringConverter` return `false` for `GetStandardValuesExclusive` and that is it.

Look here:

```
internal class cmbKutoviNagiba : StringConverter
{
      public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
      {
          return FALSE;    // <----- just highlight! remember to write it lowecase
      }

      public override TypeConverter.StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(
          ITypeDescriptorContext context)
      {
          string[] a = { "0", "15", "30", "45", "60", "75", "90" };
          return new StandardValuesCollection(a);
      }

      public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
      {
          return true;
      }
  }
```

I wrote `FALSE` in capital letters, just to make you easyer to see it. Please put it in small letters :)

Comment: BTW: The override of `GetStandardValuesExclusive` seems only to get called when used in a class that derives from `StringConverter`. It  seems to not get called when you derive your class from `TypeConverter`.